# Declare an exception not having to be handled?

Tags: java, exception

In Java, when I decide to throw an exception, is it possible to define this Exception as not having to be handled?

Thanks :-)

(I am on Java 7)

Comment: Did you do the java tutorial?

Comment: Be careful with runtime exceptions, though. Use them wisely.

Answer (score 8):

Any `Exception` that is a child type of [`RuntimeException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/RuntimeException.html) is not required to be handled.  This is called an unchecked exception.

That said, you can still choose to handle it, should you feel that it is necessary.

Answer (score 1):

It can be achieved by throwing a [unchecked exception.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/runtime.html) [RuntimeException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/RuntimeException.html) are unchecked exception which the calling program need not handle. Any sub-class like ClassCastException etc, are derived from RuntimeException and you need not worry about handling them.